# Добавление фото из Instagram в новые посты через админку

Tags: django, django-admin

Хочу добавить в административный сайт Django возможность, при создании нового поста, вставить в него фото из моего instagram (вернее, из instagram конечного пользователя сайта). Пока единственный путь, который нащупал - сильно переворотить админку, но как-то это низкоуровнево, не по-джанговски. Может кто подскажет, есть-ли путь проще (может какое готовое решение, коими славится Django)? Или хотя бы подскажите, куда копать.

Comment: А как должно происходить это добавление? Ссылку на пост в поле вставлять или еще как-то?

Comment: Воспользщоваться API инстаграмма или заходить на открытую страницу пользовалетя и парсить ее. Сильно переворачивать ее не надо. добавляете метод для view, добавляете в get_urls(). пишите свой виджет для поля выбора изображения и все. остальное - JS, который будет манипулировать данными в админке. Чуть сложновато, но реализуемо

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров изначально я задумывал, что в админке пользователь жмякает на кнопку и из списка изображений в его Instagram, выбирает несколько фоток. Они вставляются в виде слайдера, который будет как часть контента. Где-то посередине поста.

Comment: @ZaArs спасибо. Видимо на досуге замучу либу для джанги. Ну или забью =D

Comment: Оформил как ответ, раз он вам подошел)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользоваться API инстаграмма или заходить на открытую страницу пользовалеля и парсить ее.

Сильно переворачивать админку не надо - добавляете метод для view, добавляете в get_urls(). Пишите свой виджет для поля выбора изображения и все. Остальное - JS, который будет манипулировать данными в админке. Чуть сложновато, но реализуемо